# How can I purge a mysql setup

Tags: debian, mariadb

I installed mariadb-server-10.0 and php-mysql with the following.

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server-10.0 php-mysql
```

I setup with `sudo mysql_secure_installation`

I created a database for WordPress with

```
https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/7
    Set up WordPress Database
    mysql -u root -p
    create database wordpress;
```

So far, so good, but before installing Wordpress I obviously did something wrong, and can no longer log on to mysql with my password.

**How can I completely purge the existing setup?**

I tried

```
sudo apt purge mariadb-server-10.0 php-mysql
```

and re-installed, but it still objects to my password.

If worst comes to worst, I can restore from an old backup, but I would like to avoid this.

Comment: why do you want to remove MySQL rather than fix the error? you could still recover by logging into mysql as root and changing the user credentials

Comment: @Bart it is the root password it doesn't like!

Comment: reset root password then: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Answer (score 1):

Run the purge and after delete the data and the config files and try again to install it.

Delete config and data:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```